# HTML5 - Detecting image size, resizing canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I recently made and hosted Catifier.com.

It's working pretty good, except I have a bug with saving I have to work out, and it stretches images when you set them as the background.

Portrait images look horrible.

Would it be possible to detect the width and height of the image a user pastes in the box, then resize the canvas accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load your picture in a DOM element to know its size.

So basicly when you want to do it, here are the steps :

- Add your picture in an invisible DOM element.
- You will be able to get picture width and heignt when onload event is lauched.
- Then create your canvas depending those two variables.

All can be done in very few javascript lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just gonna write up a very generic and likely not fully functional way to do this real quick just to give more of an idea.

```
var img = document.getElementByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  var width = img[i].width,
      height = img[i].height;

  // do some stuff with the img[i] width and height here if you like. for each image on the page... 
}
```

Not how you'd end up actually doing it but it's just as simple as doing, img.width or height. If that helps more at all.